# Is there a way to test the presence of a Google Map overlay?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm creating heatmap overlays on a google map, and I need to clear the old data before overlaying the new data. In order to do this I'm using the following code:

```
heatmap.setMap(null)
heatmap.setMap(map)
```

This works if the heatmap has been set, but it will not work if it's the first time the user creates an overlay. I was wondering if there is a way to test the presence of an overlay. This code has not been working, but I'm thinking along the lines of:

```
if(heatmap.setMap(map) == true){
    heatmap.setMap(null)
} else {
    ...
}
```

The most important thing is testing the presence of an overlay. Does anybody know if there is something I could place in the if condition that would tell me if that overlay already exists?

Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with DOM Break points from the [Developers Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-mutation-events).

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this [if heatmap is not null, and it has a setMap method, call setMap(null)]:

```
if (heatmap && heatmap.setMap){
    heatmap.setMap(null)
}
// code to create or recreate the heatmap
heatmap.setMap(map)
```